# JavaScript Make Tabs

Tags: javascript, class, tabs, urlvariables

So, I am trying to make a "tabs menu", like this: http://flowplayer.org/tools/tabs/index.html
(but i dont want to use this.)
So, I tried to use url variables to set the active menu item.
Code:

```
onload=function(){
    //Check if editPage is set
    if (gup("editPage")) {
        gupname = gup("editPage");
        var x = "contentEditListItem"+gupname; 
        var y = document.getElementsByClassName(x);
        y.className = "contentEditListItemActive";
    } 
}
function gup( name )
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
  var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
  if( results == null )
    return "";
  else
    return results[1];
}
```

The gup function works well, I get the wanted classname ("contentEditListItem"+gupname).
Why it is staying unchanged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a `NodeList` (kind of `Array`), so setting a property on that is not affecting the *elements* that it contains, but only the `NodeList` itself, which has no effect.

You could set the class name of the first element, for example, like this:

```
y[0].className = "contentEditListItemActive";
```

Or, if you want all elements have their class name changed, you could iterate over the `NodeList`:

```
for(var i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    y[i].className = "contentEditListItemActive";
}
```